# How to browse data in MySQL database on Amazon EC2?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deployed my Rails app to Amazon EC2 server (Ubuntu), but I am thinking how to connect to MySQL database from terminal (SSL) and manually check data in database.

How to do that? I see in the `database.yml` file some credentials, but don't know how to connect/log in into MySQL on EC2 instance.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried SSHing?

Comment: What do you mean? I can log in through SSH to my EC instance, but I don't know how to get into MySQL from this point.

Comment: Try this in the root of your rails app: `bundle exec rails db -p`

Comment: I've also had luck with http://www.sequelpro.com (you can configure it to connect to your DB server via SSH - this is for Mac OSX only, I'm sure there are other tools depending on your platform)

Answer (score 1):

There's no special magic involved here.  An EC2 server is just... a server.  This is not hosting like heroku or godaddy where your database is going to be hosted on a different db server.

Unless you explicitly setup a separate db server (which I don't think you did), you've got an entire virtual machine running Ubuntu, and the db server is most likely running on the same machine.

So you can ssh into the machine and just run the standard mysql client.  Docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html.

If you want to use some gui software such as sequel pro mentioned in one of the comments, you'll need to open up the ports in the aws console.  Amazon closes all the ports by default.  Do this to open up the port:

- Open up the AWS control panel
- Go to 'Security Groups'
- Select the security group in the panel (you probably only have one).
- Click the 'Inbound' tab.
- Select Mysql from the dropdown list
- Save the rule

This will open up port 3306 and enable you to use an external tool to see the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call some sql to the database just to verify small amount of data, you can try doing these:

```
sql_statement = 'SELECT * FROM users'
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_statement).to_a
```